# Custom async validator returning type error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am building a graphQL-based Angular application with some custom async validators for reactive forms. This validator below in particular is checking the database for the email to see if it already exists:

```
emailAsyncValidator: AsyncValidatorFn = (control: FormControl): Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
    return new Promise((res, _) => {
        this.checkEmailGQL.fetch(control.value).pipe(map(result => 
            result.data.checkEmail.matches ? res({emailExists: true}) : res(null)
            ), catchError((_) =>
            of(res({asyncValidationFailed: true}))
        ))
    });
}
```

However, this gets me the following TS error:

```
Type 'Observable<ValidationErrors>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ValidationErrors> | Observable<ValidationErrors>'.
      Type 'Observable<ValidationErrors>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ValidationErrors>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2322)
```

What is the issue here actually? Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: you are not returning promise add return before `return this.checkEmailGQL....`

Comment: @KamranKhatti I am wrapping that whole section of code in a return new Promise block with a resolve function as an argument in order to be able to handle server-related errors efficiently. In theory, this should work.

Comment: I think you don't need to return a promise at all, why just not to return `this.checkEmailGQL.fetch...`?

Comment: @vitaliykotov That goes not go in line with what Angular validators want. In this case, they want a promise that wraps a null or an object. Doing that does not fix the type error.